# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loading' of 'orderPay' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I'm creating node/react web shop and i have problem with this:

```
     const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay);
     const {
        loading: loadingPay,
        error: errorPay,
        success: successPay,
    } = orderPay;
```

where the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loading' of 'orderPay' as it is undefined.
```

i'm sure this is correct way to destructure

order actions:

```
export const payOrder = (order, paymentResult) => async (
dispatch,
getState
) => {
dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_REQUEST, payload: { order, paymentResult } });
const {
 userSignin: { userInfo },
} = getState();
try {
const { data } = Axios.put(`/api/orders/${order._id}/pay`, paymentResult, {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
});
dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS, payload: data });
} catch (error) {
const message =
  error.response && error.response.data.message
    ? error.response.data.message
    : error.message;
dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_FAIL, payload: message });
 }
};
```

now reducer part is:

```
  export const orderPayReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case ORDER_PAY_REQUEST:
    return { loading: true };
  case ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS:
    return { loading: false, success: true };
  case ORDER_PAY_FAIL:
    return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
  case ORDER_PAY_RESET:
    return {};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

i read similar questions with but they arent helping me

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an initial state for 'orderPay' which contains the attributes that you are trying to destructure. From your code, it looks like by default if the state is undefined, the value passed down to the components will be undefined. You can change your reducer to check if state is undefined and use a default value as follows :

```
export const orderPayReducer = (state = {loading : false, error : {}, success:true}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case ORDER_PAY_REQUEST:
    return { loading: true };
  case ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS:
    return { loading: false, success: true };
  case ORDER_PAY_FAIL:
    return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
  case ORDER_PAY_RESET:
    return {};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

Update the default value to whatever you wish to have there.

More on this -> https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state

Answer (score 1):

You should define `orderState` property in your initial state(reducer first param).
See this example from the docs with `todos`/`filters` (similar to your `orderState`).

The definition on the initial state([docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers)):

```
const initialState = {
  todos: [
    { id: 0, text: 'Learn React', completed: true },
    { id: 1, text: 'Learn Redux', completed: false, color: 'purple' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Build something fun!', completed: false, color: 'blue' }
  ],
  filters: {
    status: 'All',
    colors: []
  }
}
```

Selecting from state using select([docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react)):

```
const selectTodos = state => state.todos
const todos = useSelector(selectTodos)
```

Other Suggestions (My opinion):

1. When deconstructing assure the variable isn't undefined. example:

   const { loading: loadingPay, error: errorPay, success: successPay } = orderPay || {};
2. Use middleware to handle async actions on Redux ([docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)).
3. Separate your initial state from the reducer for a more readable code.
4. (Also from [docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)) It's better to track request states as a single enum value (not booleans).
   A good pattern for this is to have a state section that looks like:

   status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed',
   error: string | null

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after like 2 hours tinkering and getting fustrated I realized I forgot to add it to my store.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { postsListReducer } from "./reducers/postsReducer";


const reducer = combineReducers({
  postsList: postsListReducer,
});
```

above is my code as an example of how im importing it in my store.js. Cheers.